# Trouble plotting P(t) = 100 + 20 sin(7π t/3)

Tags: plotting, trigonometry

I'm trying to plot this but I keep getting an empty graph.

I put in:

```
Plot[P[t_] := 100 + 20 sin[(7 pi)/3] t, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Hi Lupa! Usually you do the definition of a function and the use in Plot as two sequential steps, e.g.: `P[t_]:=100+20 Sin[7 Pi t/3]; Plot[P[t],{t,0,10}]`. Notice the difference in capitalization for `Sin` and `Pi`.

Answer (score 3):

You can either define your function outside of `Plot`, then call it in `Plot` as

```
P[t_] := 100 + 20 Sin[(7 Pi)/3] t
Plot[P[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

or you can just plot the expression directly

```
Plot[100 + 20 Sin[(7 Pi)/3] t, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Part of the reason it wasn't plotting was because `sin` needs to be `Sin` (with the capital).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Lupa If this was helpful, then don't forget to upvote and accept the answer.